# Yii framework : model vs data provider

Tags: yii

1. what is the difference between model and data provider ?
2. Why actionIndex is default(generate by gii) using CActiveDataProvider, other actions use model  ? Can I also use model in actionIndex ?
3. How to pass a variable that inside a model to view, but the model is called by data provider instead ?

Answer (score 0):

a *model* is basically used to contain your objects information ( **data** ), a *data provider* is used for getting an array, containing a list (by default 10 items) of those models, **it provides your data**.

the usefulness of data providers can be seen when you want to make a simple grid with pagination (and sort and all that good stuff!). if you wanted to show 1000 records of your model, you'd have to write a `findAll()` function and put a limit of 10. then if you wanted to go to 4th page, you'd have to calculate what limit you need to apply and ....

action index was dealing with indexing unknown amount of models, so a data provider was used according to that, on the other hand, create and update functions are dealing with a single model, so a simple finding or instanciating a new model would be enough.

data providers are basically created to make our developing life easier :D

Comment: Can I say 'data providers' object is created base on a 'model' ?
And It seem data providers only handle data, not any business logic, is that right ? Sounds like model of the model to me...

Comment: you can say that a DataProvider is supposed to bring you a bunch of models